# How to return one variable from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, return-value

I am using this code:

```
var userRole = dbContext.Tables.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == userModel.descriptName);
if (userRole != null)
{
    userModel.User.Table = userRole;    
}
```

Now this code above works, but for userRole it returns both value from table (Id, Name). Now how to return only Id.

Comment: Should tag the languages you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userRole = dbContext.Tables.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == userModel.descriptName
select v.Id);
```

Comment: The logic that you recomend is what I am searcing, but, it does not offer me syntax "select" only SelectList

Comment: well actually im unable to access the code, not not able to recall

Comment: will look into it tomorrow

Comment: till then you can user 
`userRole = userRole.Id;`

Comment: It says error, that "Cannot convert source type 'int' to target type 'MySolution.Models.Table'

Comment: Thanks man it solve it. I have some mistake but I fix it :D
I have done this, because I need it to save it in database and I have done: dbUser.Roles = userRole.Id;

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
var userRole = dbContext.Tables.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == userModel.descriptName);
if (userRole != null)
{
    userModel.User.Table = userRole;
    var ID =  userModel.User.Table.Columns[1];  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I have solve it. Your sugestion is interesting also, but, It does not offer me to call first column from table?